# Stop process blocking UI and return events as they happen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to run a script and get the output as it happens to a log file. However, when I run the event it blocks the UI and waits till the end and spits out all of the output. Ideally i'd like to make it real time

```
public static void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
        {
            try
            {             
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                proc.Start();
                string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                Log.addLog(result);
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                Log.addLog(objException.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a more detailed question, it's impossible to know for sure what advice you need. However, you write that you want to *"get the output as it happens to a log file"*, which to me seems to mean that you don't want to have to wait until the process has exited to write output to the log file, but rather want to log the output as it occurs.

If so, you need to use one of the many possible asynchronous I/O mechanisms available with the `Process` class and its associated streams or readers.

For example:

```
public static async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(object command)
{
    try
    {             
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
           new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();

        await ConsumeReader(proc.StandardOutput);
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        Log.addLog(objException.Message);
    }
}

async static Task ConsumeReader(TextReader reader)
{
    string text;

    while ((text = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
    {
        Log.addLog(text);
    }
}
```

The above will write the output to your log file asynchronously, as well as provide asynchronous notification of when the process completes. Naturally, for the latter to work, you will need to `await` the call to `ExecuteCommandAsync()`. If you don't need notification of the completion of the process, then you could just leave the method signature alone (i.e. make it simply `static void`), and then ignore the `Task` object returned by `ConsumeReader()`.

If the above does not address your question, then please improve the question by providing a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to do, along with a precise description of what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Please note also that there are already numerous questions on Stack Overflow regarding asynchronous use of `Process` output, and about avoiding blocking the UI thread in general. You likely can find additional details you seek by searching the site for those topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can go all async:

```
public static async Task<string> ExecuteCommandAsync(object command)
{
    try
    {             
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        return await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        return objException.Message;
    }
}
```

Then, to consume (in an async method):

```
var message = await ExecuteCommandAsync(command);
Log.addLog(message);
```